# can python subprocess Popen accept multiple stdin streams?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

I have two files that I need to parse and merge into one file.  The files are very large in size so I'm using pipes so that I don't have any intermediate files.  The code I'm using is...

```
import subprocess

proc1 = subprocess.Popen([
    'parse_script', '-c', '0.5', '-i' path_to_file1
], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

proc2 = subprocess.Popen([
    'parse_script', '-c', '0.5', '-i' path_to_file2
], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

merge_proc = subprocess.Popen([
    'merge_outputs', '-o', path_to_output_file,
], stdin=(proc1.stdout, proc2.stdout)) # yes, I know this is an error, it's here for demonstrative purposes

merge_proc.communicate()
```

So I have two processes that parse the two files, however I need to take the stdout of these two processes and pipe them both to the stdin of the merging process.  The code above demonstrates what I'm trying to do.  So my question is; how do I accept multiple stdin pipes into my file merging process?  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Is your parse_script output large as well or only the source file?

Comment: Yes, the parse_script output will be very large.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot merge two subprocess.PIPEs, but you can use your own pipe as a workaround. Like this:

```
import subprocess
import os

read_end, write_end = os.pipe()

proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '/tmp'], stdout=write_end)

proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '/etc'], stdout=write_end)
os.close(write_end)
merge_proc = subprocess.Popen([
    '/tmp/merge_outputs'], stdin=read_end)

merge_proc.wait()
```

This uses `os.pipe()` to create a pipe of your own. Your "source" subprocesses write their standard output to the write end of this pipe and your merge process reads from the other end. This is entirely supported.

After your source processes complete, you should close the write end of your pipe. This will then allow the merge process to finish processing when all data has been received.